# I must be misunderstanding PHP's "use" keyword

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm using an application with PHP's namespaces and I thought that instead of me doing...

```
\MyNamespace\ClassName::MyFunction();
```

I could do

```
use MyNamespace;
ClassName::MyFunction();
```

if I'm using that object many times within the page.  This isn't working for me.  I keep having to use the first method.

What am I missing about the `use` keyword?

Comment: `use \MyNamespace\ClassName as something`  .... `something::MyFunction()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`use` will basically create a link to its argument, using the last name (unless otherwise speicified). To use `ClassName` without having to specify its namespace all the time, you have to import the following:

```
use \MyNamespace\ClassName;
```

So, `ClassName` is set as a reference to the type located at `\MyNamespace\ClassName`.

It’s similar to how Java’s `import` works, and not like C#’s `using` which imports the whole namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import/use the exact class name:

```
use MyNamespace\ClassName;

ClassName::myFunction();
```

You can also use the following syntax:

```
use MyNamespace\MySubnamespace;

MySubnamespace\MyClassname::doSth();
MySubnamespace\AnotherClassname::doSthElse();
```

which allows you to use several classes from one namespace without need to import every single one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like:

```
use \MyNamespace\ClassName as MyClassName;

MyClassName::MyFunction();
```